# How to test rendered data from API with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am currently a beginner learning how to write tests for React apps and components.

I have begun to be able to test based on how components appear on screen using `toBeInTheDocument()`, however I am struggling to understand how it would work when testing data saved to state from an API, in my `<Products>` component for example.

The documentation I have been reading has confused me further and certain sites have outdated solutions or solutions that are irrelevant to my case.

Basically, if you were to build on the testing I have already implemented, how would you go about it and what do you think would be a necessary test? Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Sandbox below:

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/ramclean/productspage/main

Answer (score 0):

-The first step is to use a tool like Jest (https://jestjs.io/) to mock the data coming from your API.

-Then when you have the data mocked you can test that the data is displaying correctly.

If you want a more end-to-end test you have to use a tool like cypress(https://www.cypress.io/) where you get real data from the API and test that it displays correctly. These are heavier and slower tests. They are often used to test the 'happy path'.